# Understanding what `is not None` MEANS

Tags: python, oop

I learning Oop and implementing in python. This is the example that is being used of teach me Oop concepts.

```
class Car(object):

    def __init__(self, wheels, miles, make, model, year, sold_on):
        """Return a new Car object."""
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.miles = miles
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.sold_on = sold_on

    def sale_price(self):
        """Return the sale price for this car as a float amount."""
        if self.sold_on is not None:
            return 0.0  # Already sold
        return 5000.0 * self.wheels

    def purchase_price(self):
        """Return the price for which we would pay to purchase the car."""
        if self.sold_on is None:
            return 0.0  # Not yet sold
        return 8000 - (.10 * self.miles)
```

So far I do not understand what the following code means.

```
if self.sold_on is not None:
    return 0.0  # Already sold
return 5000.0 * self.wheels
```

What does **is not None** mean in this context?

Comment: Do you know what `None` means? Do you know what `is not` means?

Comment: The condition is fulfilled if the *value* of `self.sold_on` is different than `None` (i.e. is not `None`).

Comment: @user2357112 I know the notation means that **if there is some value** then return 0.0

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the `None` value is an object, much like anything else. It is also a singleton (i.e. there is only ever one `None` object). It denotes a lack of value.

> The Python None object, denoting lack of value. [(Source)](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html)

In Python, the `is` keyword tests *object* equality. That is, `x is y` tests whether `x` and `y` are the same *object*, and returns `True` if they are, `False` if they are not. Accordingly, `x is not y` tests that `x` and `y` are **not** the same object.

If you extend this to your example, you are checking whether the `self.sold_on` object is **not** the same as the `None` object. Note that this will evaluate to `True` if `self.sold_on` is **anything** but `None`.

(Remember that any variable in Python is a reference to an object, so multiple variables can all refer to the same `None` object)

Answer (score -1):

It appears the creator of the class expects you to initialize a new `Car` object with `None` for the `sold_on` attribute, such as:

```
vw_bug = Car(4, 150000, 'VW', 'Bug', 1972, None)
```

Then if someone checks the sale price with the `sale_price()` method
it will return $5000 * number of wheels.

But if the car was sold on say August 8, 2017 you could, for example,
set the `sold_on` attribute to the string `'2017/08'08'`.  After that if someone checks the sale price it will return $0 since the `sold_on` attribute would no longer have the value `None`

```
vw_bug.sold_on = '2017/08/08'
```

You would need a more complete class implementation and/or doc string to tell exactly how the `Car` class is actually intended to be used.

Comment: This answer really misses the point. He's not asking about how the class `Car` could be used, he's asking how `is not None` works.